# javascript runat server arrow functions not working

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, runatserver

JavaScript runat=server

This function works fine:

```js
function test() {
  var a = {
    "ar1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  };
  if (a.ar1.some(1)) {
    return true
  }
  return false
}

test();
```

This does not. I get a syntax error:

```
function test() {
var a={"ar1":[1,2,3,4,5]};
if(a.ar1.some(x=> x==1)){
       return true
}
return false
}
```

That same code works fine on the client side. Whenever I introduce an arrow function to my runat=server, I get an error.

Why?

Comment: `if(a.ar1.some(1)){` looks pretty suspicious. `.some` should accept a *function*, not a number, as an argument. See snippet - it currently throws an error.

Comment: Please post the error message. Also, arrow functions are an ES6 feature are you sure your server side uses ES6?

Comment: Well, I'm sure of it now and it's not. How do I go about updating IIS/Windows server to update to ES6?

Comment: And nevermind about that. It does not appear that Jscript is supporting ES6 at this point.